# select a specific range from a numpy 2d array to plot values

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

for example with a numpy array like the following,

a=([1,2,3,4,5], [100,200,300,400,500]) and x=a[0] and y=a[1]

how can I plot xy where 2 < x < 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try masks on arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([100,200,300,400,500])

# b contains true when corresponding value of x is outside 2 < x < 4
b = np.ma.masked_outside(x, 2, 4).mask

# x2 originates from x, but values 2 < x < 4 are stripped (according to the boolean variables contained in b), the same is done with y2
x2 = x[~b]
y2 = y[~b]

print 'x2', x2
print 'y2', y2
```

When its only about plotting, you could just use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis((2,4,None,None)) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: when plotting its better to use your suggestion of using masked arrays to save memory in some cases. this was really helpful, thank you @Simon

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a=array(([1,2,3,4,5], [100,200,300,400,500]))
>>> a[:, (2 < a[0])*(a[0] < 4)]
array([[  3],
       [300]])
```

Since that just gives a single point, let's choose another range:

```
>>> a[:, (1.5 < a[0])*(a[0] < 4.5)]
array([[  2,   3,   4],
       [200, 300, 400]])
```

To explain, `(1.5 < a[0])*(a[0] < 4.5)` is a vector of true and false values.  It is true whenever x is between 1.5 and 4.5.  Numpy can use such boolean vectors to select just those values. We use that for the second axis.

For the first axis, if we had used 0 (as in `a[0, (1.5 < a[0])*(a[0] < 4.5)]`), we would have gotten just the `x`-values between 1.5 and 4.5.  If we had used 1, we would have gotten just the y values that correspond to that x-range.  If we want an array with both the `x` and `y` values, we can use `:` for the first axis which means "all".

If we want to plot those values:

```
b = a[:, (1.5 < a[0])*(a[0] < 4.5)]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p = plt.plot(b[0], b[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: thats great thank you @John1024 this is ideal for selective plotting to save memory